# How to map through json response in react using options tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

I am a beginner in React and I am trying to output a json response in a dropdown. My response looks like this

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {author: {…}, template_content: {…}, template_id: "9d288846-3418-4086-a15b-a2c00a823416", template_name: "name"}
1: {author: {…}, template_content: {…}, template_id: "d4646d5d-41df-4540-9a4f-bdc50bfa9fa1", template_name: "name"}
2: {author: {…}, template_content: {…}, template_id: "fe74ada6-e28c-433e-a0b1-fddfa20aaa18", template_name: "name"}
3: {author: {…}, template_content: {…}, template_id: "3f5deba5-532e-4043-a694-30a6b5fc3b1a", template_name: "hello name"}
4: {author: {…}, template_content: {…}, template_id: "73d6ecc4-338d-4603-9c68-470f0183704e", template_name: "hello"}
5: {author: {…}, template_content: {…}, template_id: "6142f855-9770-4889-9f37-cc1cacaca0db", template_name: "nhnhgngx"}
```

I want to take the `template_id` show it in the dropdown values. So far I am using map function to do this, but I was facing a Type error. After googling a but I realized map is a function of arrays so it won't work. But i am not able to find a workaround on how to do this. Here is my code below:

```
static getTemplates = (callback) => {
    const url = API_BASE_URL + TEMPLATE_CREATE
    let apiResponse = { response: null, error: false, msg: '' };

    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': getAccessToken()
        },
        responseType: 'json',
        responseEncoding: 'utf8'
    })
        .then(response => {
            apiResponse.response = response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            apiResponse.response = error;
            apiResponse.error = true;
        })
        .finally(() => {
            callback(apiResponse);
        });
};

getTemplatesApiResponse = apiResponse => {
    const statusCode = apiResponse.response.status;
    if (statusCode === 200) {
        this.setState({ templates: apiResponse.response.data.result });
    } else {
        this.setState({ error: true, errorMessage: '' });
        this.openNotificationWithIcon('error', 'No Templates found', apiResponse.response.data.error.msg);
    }
};
GetTemplates = (e) =>{
            XRayApi.getTemplates(this.getTemplatesApiResponse)
        }
                        <Select
                        native
                        label="Select-Template"
                        onClick={this.GetTemplates} 
                        >
                        <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                         {
                            templates.map(x=> <option>{x}</option>)
                        } 
                        </Select>
```

It is giving me the following error:

> TypeError: templates.map is not a function

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

How to solve this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `x.template_id` for `value` attribute and between the `<option>` tag.

So technically [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates through the array what you get from the API call, `x` represents the current element. The current element has a property `template_id` what you can use in both cases.

The error what you see is related to call `.map()` on `null` value. Probably you can add an extra `null` check for `templates` because it is coming asynchronously from the API, so adding `templates && templates.map()` would help as I showed in my example.

I would try to add as the following - note here I added `this.state` before `templates`:

```
<Select native label="Select-Template" onClick={this.GetTemplates} >
    <option aria-label="None" value="" />
    {
       this.state.templates &&
       this.state.templates.map(x=> <option value={x.template_id}>{x.template_id}</option>)
    } 
</Select>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @matata.ptt13 Just extended with `null` check part, probably that solves the issue.

Comment: Can you please add to your question the code for `this.GetTemplates()`, how `templates` is defined and also the constructor where you define the state? Probably the issue is something else than what I thought firstly.

Comment: added. Please check

Comment: Oh, I see now, I guess it's a missing `this.state.templates` part. You define the `templates` within the state thus you can access it like `this.state.templates`. Just extended my answer with that.

Comment: actually I decalred templates just above my return statement as `const templates = this.state.templates;`

Comment: That was declared from the start